# imap_fetchstructure () doesn't retrieve attachments (parts)

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to retrieve and read attachments from my IMAP account via `imap_fetchstructure()` but while it reads general attachments such as PDF, Images etc, the specific attachment which I want to read (a name.bin file) doesn't get captured in the code. As you can see in the attached screenshot there is an attachment in the mail.

[image]

This is the response I get;

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 3
    [encoding] => 3
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => OCTET-STREAM
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [bytes] => 58
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 0
    [parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Does it have a body?  Can you dump the MIME and attach it?

Comment: Email body doesn't have any content but the attachment consists of a 8bit ASCII message.

Answer (score 1):

The sender sent you a 58-byte attachment with content-type application/octet-stream and without such details as a suggested filename, so that's all the information you get from retrieving `bodystructure`, which is about the body**structure**, as the name implies. If you want the attachment **content**, not just its structure, itself you have to retrieve it.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not an expert in PHP, could you please help me to do this? I tried few examples but couldn’t get it retrieved